# What's the privileges of an account under windows task schedule?

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks, dtexec

I use dtexec to run ssis packages and I use the dtexec...>e:\log.txt command to write console messages to a txt file. It works fine if I run it manually, but it is not working if I put it in task schedule. It seems no permission to create the log.txt file. I checked the "Run with highest Privileges" option. But I use the same account as I do this manually.

Comment: Most likely, drive `E:\` is not mapped when running from scheduler.

Comment: e: is a local drive

Comment: Does your account have the [right to log on as batch job](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc957131.aspx)?